# Item frequency plots from object of class transactions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, arules

Package [`arules`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/) enables to quickly read transactions data (for mining association rules and frequent itemsets) which is achieved with a dedicated *[transactions-class](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/arules/html/transactions-class.html)*. We can also quickly create quite raw and boring item frequency plots using `itemFrequencyPlot` function from this package (with some arguments for customisation):

```
library(arules)
data("Groceries")
itemFrequencyPlot(Groceries, topN = 20)
```

[image]

I would like to recreate such plots with more visual flexibility in `ggplot2` without overly excessive coding but I can't find any out-of-box dedicated functions to achieve this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't find any out-of-box dedicated functions to achieve this

Well, I guess you can build one like this:

```
library(arules)
library(tidyverse)
data("Groceries")
itemFrequencyGGPlot <- function(x, topN) {
  library(tidyverse)
  x %>%
    itemFrequency %>%
    sort %>%
    tail(topN) %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
    ggplot(aes(reorder(rowname, `.`),`.`)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_flip()
}  
itemFrequencyGGPlot(Groceries, 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats a nice "pipe shot", much appreciated.